# Unit testing AngularJS Controller whilst following best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We are building an AngularJS app following some of the best practice guidelines which are outlined [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controllers).

Am specifically interested in testing a very simple controller to get up and running with karma.

The controller code is:

```
angular.module('ttn').controller('Login', Login);

function Login(){

    var login = this;
    login.title = 'foo bar content here etc';

}
```

And the spec code is:

```
describe('Controller: Login', function () {

    beforeEach(module('ttn'));

    var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        controller = $controller('Login', {
            $scope: scope
        });

        scope.$digest();

    }));

    it('should define a title', function () {
        expect(scope.title).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

This fails with expecting undefined to be defined.

If I change the controller to:

```
angular.module('ttn').controller('Login', Login);

function Login($scope){

    $scope.title = 'foo bar whatsit jibber';

}
```

The test then passes as expected.  I am not sure how to reference the controller written in the manner outlined on the above link to get the test to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your controller doesn't use $scope, you shouldn't be injecting it and using it in your tests. Instead you should be checking for title on your controller:

```
describe('Controller: Login', function () {

    beforeEach(module('ttn'));

    var controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {

        controller = $controller('Login', {});

    }));

    it('should define a title', function () {
        expect(controller.title).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PODyrhx2Nc4fA9gof7nO?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you.  I would have carried on if you had not answered in the correct manner.  Appreciate it.